# ckeditor - Add class to the parent span of toolbar button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am able to add class to the button:

```
  editor.ui.addButton(_buttonName,
            {
                'label': 'Switch Toolbar',
                icon: CKEDITOR.getUrl(this.path) + 'images/' + pluginIcon,
                className: 'cke_switchtoolbar',
                command: _pluginCommand
            });
```

But I want to apply some styling to its parent spans also.
How can I do it.

```
<span id="cke_403" class="cke_toolbar" aria-labelledby="cke_403_label" role="toolbar">
    <span id="cke_403_label" class="cke_voice_label">Expandable</span>
    <span class="cke_toolbar_start"></span>
    <span class="cke_toolgroup" role="presentation">
        <a id="cke_404" class="cke_switchtoolbar cke_button cke_button__switchbar cke_button_off cke_switchtoolbar" "="" href="javascript:void('Switch Toolbar')" title="Switch Toolbar" tabindex="-1" hidefocus="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="cke_404_label" aria-haspopup="false" onkeydown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(44,event);" onfocus="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(45,event);" onmousedown="return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(46,event);" onclick="CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(47,this);return false;">
            <span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__switchbar_icon" style="background-image:url(http://localhost:55244/Content/ckeditor/plugins/switchbar/images/arrow-downward.png?t=D08E);background-position:0 undefinedpx;">&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="cke_404_label" class="cke_button_label cke_button__switchbar_label">Switch Toolbar</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <span class="cke_toolbar_end"></span>
</span>
```

In this case i want to add styles to span with class '`cke_toolgroup`' and class '`cke_toolbar`' having inner button with class '`cke_switchtoolbar`' but, there can be many spans with same class '`cke_toolgroup`' or '`cke_toolbar`'.

Comment: Is the class name you gave to btn unique?

Comment: Ok, I thought you need to change inner editor document,my bad I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

if the class name you gave the button is unique, you can use some jquery to change styling after you added custom button to CKEditor toolbar like this:

```
$(".cke_toolbar").closets("span").addClass(yourClass);
```

the `closest("span")` part, finds nearest parent that is span, you can use any other selector if you need.

Comment: $(editor.window.getFrame().$ ).contents() is returning the iFrame but that button tollbar is not part of the iFrame itself.

Answer (score 0):

you may also target parent span with css like `#cke_1_top .cke_toolbox span:last-child` or `#cke_1_top .cke_toolbox span:nth-child(n)`

`#cke_1_top` is a main parent span and `.cke_toolbox` wrap all toolbar span, with both span you can target any child span

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!